# AWS Cloudformation: Conditionally create properties of resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I know that it is possible via the use of [Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) to conditionally (what else?) create resources.

I am trying to find a way though to conditionally create properties of resources;

in my case I am creating several `EC2` instances in a subnet with default public ip assignment = `false`.

Sometimes though for debugging purposes I want my instances to get public IPs.

Now I have to comment in/out the SG/Subnet and the `NetworkInterfaces` properties below (those do not go together)

```
  myEC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      Comment: My EC2 Instance
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          commands:
            01_provision:
              command:
                !Sub |
                  sed -i "s/somestring/${somevar}/" /some/path/
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT4M
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [ MyAamiMap, 'myami', amiid ]
      InstanceType: "t2.2xlarge"
      # SubnetId: !Ref SBNDemo1
      # SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref SGInternalDemo]
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: "SGInternalDemo"
          SubnetId:
            Ref: "SBNDemo1"
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            # Start cfn-init
            /usr/local/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r myEC2 --region ${AWS::Region} || echo 'Failed to run cfn-init'
            # All done so signal success
            /usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource myEC2 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you know you can now use aws lambda in cloud formation, can that be useful in your case ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This might be a little late, but I recently had a same question.

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#w2ab1c21c24c21c39b8c10), you can use **Fn::If** to set properties accordingly.

The template will look like:

```
Properties:
  ImageId: !FindInMap [ MyAamiMap, 'myami', amiid ]
  InstanceType: "t2.2xlarge"
  # SubnetId: !Ref SBNDemo1
  # SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref SGInternalDemo]
  NetworkInterfaces:
    !If
    - YourCondition
    - 
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
      DeviceIndex: "0"
      GroupSet:
        - Ref: "SGInternalDemo"
      SubnetId:
        Ref: "SBNDemo1"
    - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

AWS::NoValue means there will be no NetworkInterfaces properties set.

Comment: This "AWS::NoValue" is what I've been looking for months now to conditionale enable webhook for a CodeBuild project based on a parameter. 

Is it just me or this isn't anywhere nearly documented enough?

Thanks man!

Comment: Awesome!  I think I had tried this previously, but I put the !If statement above NetworkInterfaces instead of inside of it and I wasn't successful.  I'm glad my coworker sent me a link to this!

Comment: tried it with serverless lambda function, didn't work. `Events:
        !Ref "AWS::NoValue"`

Comment: Note:  this doesn't work on the top level of resource properties, even when the top level property is optional.  For example, you couldn't conditionally define `instanceType` property using an `!If` block (you would get a syntax error), and that is a significant limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding but this sounds like a parameter use case rather than a condition use case.  I say that because you do not say under what conditions you would like a public ip.  Just "sometimes for debugging purposes"  How would the template know that you are debugging?  You have to tell it with a parameter.

check out the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

So you could have a public ip parameter and a subnet id parameter and pass in what you like at stack creation.

One way that conditions could be useful is to create a debug parameter that would toggle public/private ip and subnet.  Is this what you were thinking of?

To use conditions on properties use the IF function

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html

I suggest setting your public subnet to provide a public ip on launch, and of course ensuring your private subnet does not do that.  Then just pass the subnet in as a parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer (accepted one) didn't work for me. I needed this:

```
  NetworkInterfaces:
    - !If
      - YourCondition
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
        DeviceIndex: "0"  
        ...
      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Traps on the way:

- Without the hyphen before the !If, I was unable to deploy.
- Watch out for the proper indentation.
- You might find other answer using `- -` instead of `-`. That is probably wrong. 
   *Details*: `- -` will create an Array. `-` will create a dictionary (key: value). The latter is probably what you need