# How do I use conditions in cloudformation properties?

Tags: properties, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a cloudformation template which creates a role and I want to include managed policies in the role but only if a condition is true, but cloudformation doesn't allow to do something like this:

```
"MyRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "Condition": "MyCondition":
          {
            "Ref": "EMRFullAccessManagedPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "RoleName": {
                   myRole
                    }
             }
        }
```

Is there a way to use conditions in properties this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cloudformation: Conditionally create properties of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631992/aws-cloudformation-conditionally-create-properties-of-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Fn::If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```
"ManagedPolicyArns":      
          {"Fn::If" : [
            "MyCondition",
            ["Ref": "EMRFullAccessManagedPolicy"],
            []
          ]}
```

or

```
"ManagedPolicyArns":
  { "Fn::If": 
   ["AddSageMakerAccess",    
     ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess" ],
      { "Fn::If": 
         ["AddEMRFullAccessPolicy", 
         ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2" ], 
         [] 
     ] 
     } 
   ] 
   },
```

The above will work if AddSageMakerAccess and AddEMRFullAccessPolicy are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I tried to do:

"ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "AddSageMakerAccess",
              [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
              ],
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "AddEMRFullAccessPolicy",
              [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2"
              ],
              []
            ]
          }
        ],
and it gives me: "Value of property ManagedPolicyArns must be of type List of String"

Comment: You need to chain your ifs. See my edited answer.

Comment: It works now,
Thank you!!